# Configure NLog programmatically, web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nlog

I have following Nlog config section in my web.config (modified to show only relevant info)

```
<nlog>
    <targets async="true">
      <target name="mail" type="Mail"
              body="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss} - ${level} [${logger}] - ${message} ${newline}${newline}${event-context:item=OtherInfo}${newline}${newline}${exception:maxInnerExceptionLevel=2:format=ToString}${newline}${newline}" 
              subject="[${machinename}] ${logger}"
              to="mail@domain.com" encoding="UTF-8" from="anotheremail@domain.com" smtpServer="" enableSsl="true" smtpAuthentication="Basic"
      />
    </targets>
    <targets>
      <target name="mailsync" type="Mail" body="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss} - ${level} [${logger}] - ${message} ${newline}${newline}${event-context:item=OtherInfo}${newline}${newline}${exception:maxInnerExceptionLevel=2:format=ToString}${newline}${newline}" subject="[${machinename}] ${logger}"
              to="mail@domain.com" encoding="UTF-8" from="anotheremail@domain.com" smtpServer="" enableSsl="true" smtpAuthentication="Basic"
      />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" level="Error" writeTo="mail" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

I am updating the configuration via code in Application_Start,

```
var config = LogManager.Configuration;
const string targetName = "mail";

var wrapper = (AsyncTargetWrapper) config.FindTargetByName(targetName);
wrapper.WrappedTarget.SmtpServer = "hostname";
wrapper.WrappedTarget.SmtpUserName = "username";
wrapper.WrappedTarget.SmtpPassword = "password";

config.RemoveTarget(targetName);
config.AddTarget(targetName, wrapper);

LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

However, when I log any errors, the emails are not being sent. I have an additional file target (not shown in the code snippet), that contains the error message. That tells me the errors are getting logged, but somehow not sent via email.

If instead of updating the config via code, if I hard code the values in the web.config, then the emails get sent. I have verified that the smtp values that I am using via code are valid.

I did search through many similar questions on SO, but I haven't yet found one that mentions a solution that works for me.

**EDIT:**

Based on Xharze's answer, I enabled exceptions, internal logging and I also outputted the values of the target after I had made my changes. The internal log showed an exception about a `MailAdrress` being the incorrect format. So I checked all target values that accept an email address and I found the issue. The `from` property of the target accepts an email address whereas I was providing it a display name!

Comment: Could you try enabling throw exceptions and the interalnal log, and post it? It may provide more information. See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: @Xharze, thanks mate. The combination of enabling exception, internal logging and outputting the values of target helped identify the issue. In my production code I was setting the `From` property of the target to display name instead of the actual from email id. Anyway, if you could post an answer containing the content of your comment, I will mark that as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try enabling throw exceptions and the interalnal log, and post it? It may provide more information. See github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting.